# SQL Server 2012 get results as JSON

Tags: sql, sql-server, json, sql-server-2012

My select returns 02:18:07

```
;WITH DEMO(ID, FromTime, ToTime) AS
(
    SELECT TOP 1
        ID
       ,CONVERT(DATETIME,FromTime,120) AS FromTime
       ,CONVERT(DATETIME,ToTime,120) AS ToTime
    FROM (VALUES (1,'2016-09-03 18:14:47.000','2016-09-03 20:32:54.000')
                ,(2,'2016-09-03 12:35:45.000','2016-09-03 15:06:06.000')
    ) AS X(ID,FromTime,ToTime)
)
SELECT
    DATEADD(SECOND,SUM(DATEDIFF(SECOND, k.FromTime, k.ToTime)) OVER 
        (
            PARTITION BY (SELECT NULL)
        ),CONVERT(TIME(0),'00:00:00',0)) AS TIME_SUM
FROM DEMO k;
```

How can I get the result as below?

> "{\"returnDate\" : [    {\"TIME_SUM\":\"02:18:07\"}]} "

Comment: Have you googled JSON SQL Server 2016 yet?  There is nothing in your query that even tells it to return as JSON.

Comment: which sql server version?

Comment: JSON is only on 2016.

Comment: I use 2012.....

Comment: Well then you have to manually hack it into JSON format.  JSON commands in SQL Server are only available in 2016.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not enough detail on what you are trying to achieve; if you really want that output only for one value shown in the question, an ugly solution is here:

```
;WITH DEMO(ID, FromTime, ToTime) AS
(
    SELECT TOP 1
        ID
       ,CONVERT(DATETIME,FromTime,120) AS FromTime
       ,CONVERT(DATETIME,ToTime,120) AS ToTime
    FROM (VALUES (1,'2016-09-03 18:14:47.000','2016-09-03 20:32:54.000')
                ,(2,'2016-09-03 12:35:45.000','2016-09-03 15:06:06.000')
    ) AS X(ID,FromTime,ToTime)
)
SELECT
    '{\"returnDate\" : [ {\"TIME_SUM\":\"' + 
     CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),DATEADD(SECOND,SUM(DATEDIFF(SECOND, k.FromTime, k.ToTime)) OVER 
     (
            PARTITION BY (SELECT NULL)
     ),CONVERT(TIME(0),'00:00:00',0))) + '\"}]}' AS TIME_SUM
FROM DEMO k
```

Answer (score 0):

From https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jocapc/2015/05/16/json-support-in-sql-server-2016/ "JSON Support in SQL Server 2016"

```
SELECT column, expression, column as alias
 FROM table1, table2, table3
 FOR JSON [AUTO | PATH]
```

Best you google for something before asking here.

Comment: OP asked for SQL Server 2012

Comment: @adnan_e not originally. The op edited the post after my reply.